# check content of string input

Tags: c#

How can I check if my input is a particular kind of string. So no numeric, no "/",...

Comment: Do you by any chance mean alphabetic (letters only) instead of string?

Comment: Do you mean, "How can I check if a string contains only characters?"

Comment: Do you mean a string consisting only of alpha-numeric characters? Can you define which characters exactly?

Comment: Are you wanting validation on a UI control, or on some backend process? If a UI, are you talking about WinForms, WebForms, Silverlight, WPF...?

Comment: if your input control is a textbox it will always be a string =)

Comment: There was little to no effort put in this question, or effort to rephrase it when others asked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, to check that an input is actually an object of type `System.String`, you can simply do:

```
bool IsString(object value)
{
    return value is string;
}
```

To check that a `string` contains only letters, you could do something like this:

```
bool IsAllAlphabetic(string value)
{
    foreach (char c in value)
    {
        if (!char.IsLetter(c))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

If you wanted to combine these, you could do so:

```
bool IsAlphabeticString(object value)
{
    string str = value as string;
    return str != null && IsAllAlphabetic(str);
}
```

Comment: Good example of both, being that the title and question don't exactly match.

Answer (score 10):

If you mean "is the string completely letters", you could do:

```
string myString = "RandomStringOfLetters";
bool allLetters = myString.All( c => Char.IsLetter(c) );
```

This is based on LINQ and the [Char.IsLetter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w.aspx) method.

Comment: @ahsteele: It actually System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo to handle this for non latin characters.

Answer (score 6):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but you can probably do it with a regular expression. For example to check that your string contains only letters in a-z or A-Z you can do this:

```
string s = "dasglakgsklg";
if (Regex.IsMatch(s, "^[a-z]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Only letters in a-z.");
}
else
{
    // Not only letters in a-z.
}
```

If you also want to allow spaces, underscores, or other characters simply add them between the square brackets in the regular expression. Note that some characters have a special meaning inside regular expression character classes and need to be escaped with a backslash.

You can also use `\p{L}` instead of `[a-z]` to match any Unicode character that is considered to be a letter, including letters in foreign alphabets.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Linq;
...

bool onlyAlphas = s.All(c => (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'));
```

Comment: Don't get me wrong: regex has its uses. But for a simple, single-pass algorithm like this, it's overkill. I like Reed's answer more, though. Didn't know about `Char.IsLetter`.

Comment: @Luiscencio: How am I being brutal?

Comment: I think Luiscencio meant that you used brute force to solve it. I would have written a for loop. You solution using LINQ is far less brute force than that.

Comment: Huh. I always thought of brute force as having to do with performance. Brute force would have been throwing all valid characters into an array and doing a doubly-nested loop to make sure that all the characters in that string are one of those characters. Not having known about Char.IsLetter, the approach I took seemed pretty elegant to me. To each his own, though.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (have not tested) may fit your (vague) requirement.

```
if (input is string)
{
    // test for legal characters?
    string pattern = "^[A-Za-z]+$";
    if (Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern))
    {
         // legal string? do something 
    }

    // or
    if (input.Any(c => !char.IsLetter(c)))
    {
         // NOT legal string 
    }
}
```