# Adding Validation to Prevent String Input

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to prevent a user from entering a `TimeZoneId` of type `string`. Currently, the validation is not catching this issue. How can I prevent a user from entering a string value?

**Validator in my Provider:**

*Currently, my `AddValidator` prevents a user from entering a null value*

```
  AddValidator(p => p.TimeZoneID != null && projectValidator.IsTimeZoneIdInvalid(p.TimeZoneID.Value), "TimeZoneId", "Invalid time zone ID");
```

**I've tried adding the following, but it doesn't work. It returns an error stating Cannot apply operator '!=' to operands of type 'System.Nullable':**

```
    AddValidator(p => p.TimeZoneID != null && p.TimeZoneID != typeof(string) && projectValidator.IsTimeZoneIdInvalid(p.TimeZoneID.Value), "TimeZoneId", "Invalid time zone ID");
```

Comment: What type of control are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by `control`?

Comment: I'm thinking this can be done by modifying the `lambda` expression

Comment: Posted an answer let me know if it helps at all

Comment: How do the user send TimeZoneId to the application? What I wonder is if it is via html or do you have like a web service anyone can connect to or what is it? If it is an MVC application I would use model binding etc... but I'll get back to that when I know what you are doing :)

Comment: @CodeChaser did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: @psoshmo, I ended up not needing this validation, but your answer was very helpful. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a little unclear what you want exactly so here are some options:

Quoting from @Dan Tao from the thread [check content of string input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293241/check-if-input-is-type-of-string):

Well, to check that an input is actually an object of type System.String,   you can simply do:

```
bool IsString(object value)
{
return value is string;
}
```

To check that a string contains only letters, you could do something like this:

```
bool IsAllAlphabetic(string value)
{
foreach (char c in value)
{
    if (!char.IsLetter(c))
        return false;
}

return true;
}
```

If you wanted to combine these, you could do so:

```
bool IsAlphabeticString(object value)
{
string str = value as string;
return str != null && IsAllAlphabetic(str);
}
```

Using these methods you could do something like:

```
AddValidator(p => p.TimeZoneID != null && !IsString(p.TimeZoneID) && projectValidator.IsTimeZoneIdInvalid(p.TimeZoneID.Value), "TimeZoneId", "Invalid time zone ID");
```